# Packaging custom AOSP 4.0.4

Tags: android, packaging, android-source, ota

Having successfully compiled AOSP 4.0.4 with proprietary drivers and kernal I am looking to distribute the rom. However, I am stuck with the following files in my out folder:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1           9 Jun 20 14:32 android-info.txt
-rw-r--r--  1     4120576 Jun 20 17:20 boot.img
-rw-rw-r--  1       17238 Jun 20 16:52 clean_steps.mk
drwxrwxr-x  4        4096 Jun 20 17:13 data/
-rw-rw-r--  1       44170 Jun 20 17:23 installed-files.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1     3952256 Jun 20 17:20 kernel*
drwxrwxr-x  3        4096 Jun 20 17:55 TA-INF/
drwxrwxr-x 15        4096 Jun 20 17:23 obj/
-rw-rw-r--  1         555 Jun 20 16:52 previous_build_config.mk
-rw-rw-r--  1      164422 Jun 20 17:09 ramdisk.img
-rw-rw-r--  1      504620 Jun 20 17:20 ramdisk-recovery.img
drwxrwxr-x  3        4096 Jun 20 17:20 recovery/
-rw-r--r--  1     4460544 Jun 20 17:20 recovery.img
drwxrwxr-x  8        4096 Jun 20 17:09 root/
drwxrwxr-x  5        4096 Jun 20 17:09 symbols/
drwxrwxr-x 13        4096 Jun 20 17:09 system/
-rw-r--r--  1   148298892 Jun 20 17:23 system.img
-rw-r--r--  1   140823532 Jun 20 17:16 userdata.img
```

How do I automagically package the following into a distributable and signed `.zip` file? (Also an explanation of how to sign would be great!)

I tried running `make otapackage` but that doesn't work -- I assume that's for Cyanogenmod only builds, which this is not.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How about: make updatepackage

Answer (score 0):

So to expand on @skoperst comment, what you want to do is call make updatepackage to generate a single .zip file which can be installed to a device using fastboot. i.e.:

```
fastboot update -w [filename]
```

As for signing, the zip it self doesn't get signed per say, it's more like various parts of AOSP are signed with various keys. You can find these keys in build/target/product/security. On any given Android.mk you may see something along the lines of:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

That means that that module is signed with the platform key. Then various parts of AOSP will check module's / package's signatures to see if they have the correct permissions to be doing the things they want to do.